# Rails - Where condition in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using nested includes on Active Record. I want to add conditions on associated models in nested Includes.
In the following code, I have to add where condition on submissions and user_tutorials associations.

How to conditionally include associated models when using .to_json on a model?

```
@courses = Course.where("course_id=?",15).includes(:course_series,{courses_languages:[{courses_tutorials:[{tutorials:[{submissions:[:users]},:user_tutorials]}]}]})

@courses.to_json(:include =>
            [:course_series,
            {:courses_languages =>
                {:include =>
                  {:courses_tutorials =>
                    {:include =>
                      {:tutorials =>
                        {:include =>
                          {:submissions =>
                            {:include =>
                              {users: {only: [:user_id]}}
                          },
                          :user_tutorials => {}
                        }
                      }              
                    }                      
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    @course=Course.where(course_id: 15).includes(:course_series).(:course_languages).user_tutorials.where(/* condition for user_tutorials */).submissions.where(/* condition for submissions */)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions directly in a where clause:

```
@courses = @courses.where(
  submissions: { /* submissions conditions */ },
  user_tutorials: { /* user_tutorial conditions */ })
```

You can also have nested conditions which are useful when your join condition repeats some tables.

For example, if you want to filter `submissions` by some user's conditions and `user_tutorials` by other user conditions, you should do the following:

```
@courses = @courses.where(
  submissions: { users: { /* will affect submissions rows only */ } },
  user_tutorials: { users: { /* will affect user_tutorials row count only */ } })
```

But in your case, seems that

```
@courses = @courses.where(
  submissions: { /* submissions conditions */ },
  user_tutorials: { /* user_tutorial conditions */ })
```

is enough.